# ESAPI: Input and output validation

Tags: web-application, appsec, penetration-test, java, validation

I am new to IT Security and I have been tasked with coming up with input and output validation for ESAPI.

So for input validation, so far I got:

```
Data Type   
Name          
Email           
Password        
Address                                       
Account Number      
Zip code                               
Comment         
CC Number   
Expiry Month    
Expiry Year 
CVN         
SSN
```

But I do not understand how output validation works. Could anyone please explain it to me with a few examples?

Answer (score 1):

You should be thinking of output encoding, rather than output validation.

Output encoding is about properly escaping special characters so they appear correctly to the user, rather than getting interpreted with their special meaning.

For example if your field contains `One is < Two`, and you are showing this on a HTML page, then you need to encode it as `One is &lt; Two`. To do this with ESAPI, you would use the encodeForHTML method.

The characters that you need to encode, and the way to encode them will vary depending where you are using the data.

For example, if you are using `One is < Two` as part of a URL, the spaces also need to be encoded, and the less than sign becomes `%3C`, and the result will be `One%20is%20%3C%20Two`. To do this with ESAPI, you would use the encodeForURL method.